# combine columns of related rows into delimited list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have text file which have the following details

```
ID     |NO|Rnk|SP1|Sp2
0000177|01|  1|  N|N
0000178|01|  1|  P|P
0000178|01|  2| GP|GP
0000179|01|  1|ORS|ORS
0000180|01|  1| GP|GP
0000181|01|  1| GP|GP
0000181|01|  2| GS|GS
0000182|01|  1| GP|GP
0000183|01|  1| FM|FM
0000183|01|  2| CM|CM
0000183|01|  3| RM|RM
```

and I have to create the Out like this

```
ID     |NO|Rnk|SPC
0000177|01|  1|N
0000178|01|  1|P GP
0000179|01|  1|ORS
0000180|01|  1|GP
0000181|01|  1|GP GS
0000182|01|  1|GP
0000183|01|  1|FM CM RM
```

welcome your suggestions...Is it possible to make using Pivot Transformation?
Please explain your answares?

Comment: It seems that you'd like to combine the unique values for the SP1 and SP2 fields into a space delimited output column. Could you elaborate on your business rules for combining rows? It seems you are grouping on ID and NO. How does Rnk factor in?

Comment: I have to Combine the ID but concatenationg of Spc Values with highest rnk and there are max 3 different Spec for ID along with the Rnk.

Comment: I made one package which have script task but Is it possible to do with pivot transformation?

Comment: No, the out of the box pivot transformation would not be of use in your case. I think your best approach would be an asynchronous script transformation.

Comment: I made one package with pivote transformation which gives me the error "[Pivot [30]] Error: Duplicate pivot key value "1"". Please guide me..

Comment: My Idea is convert into columns and thenfrom derived transformation I can concate the SP columns..

Answer (score 0):

You can do the reorganization of the data all in SQL if you import your text file into a table.  The SQL would be something like the following:

```
SELECT
  TFT.ID,
  MIN(TFT.NO) AS NO,
  MIN(TFT.Rnk) AS Rnk,
  TFT0.SPC
FROM
  TextFileTable TFT
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    TFT_D.ID,
    STUFF((SELECT ' ' + Sp2 FROM TextFileTable TFT_X WHERE TFT_D.ID = TFT_X.ID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS SPC
  FROM
    TextFileTable TFT_D
) TFT0
ON
  TFT.ID= TFT0.ID
GROUP BY
  TFT.ID,
  TFT0.SPC
ORDER BY
  TFT.ID
```

The assumptions are that Sp1 and Sp2 are always identical, you always want the minimum NO, and you always want the minimum Rank.  Starting from the innermost logic outward, you concatenate a space-delimited list of Sp2 values using the FOR XML PATH('') trick (example explanation:  http://fergusondigital.com/Blog/post.cfm/using-for-xml-path-and-stuff-to-coalesce).  Associate each list with its ID, taking DISTINCT rows to get one row per list.  Then group those rows by ID and SPC, joining by ID to get the NO and Rnk values.